# Repetitive Prints with For Loops

Tags: c++

I am currently coding a C++ project and am hung up on a certain piece of the code (literally the last piece-_-).

```
void outputException2(ofstream &outfile, int counter, Info *names)
{
    outfile << setw(70) << "EXCEPTION REPORT 2" << endl << endl;
    outfile << setw(90) << "The Following Tropical Storms were not listed in the Tropical Storm data list." << endl << endl;

    outfile << "NAME" << setw(20) << "ID" << endl;
    outfile << endl << endl;

    ifstream tropical;
    tropical.open("tropical.txt");

    //This will count how many lines have information in them or are being used.
    int count = 0;
    while (tropical)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        tropical.ignore(256,'\n');
    }
    //This is the end of that program
    Tropicals name[count];

    //Both pieces of code below will allow me to go back to the beginning of the tropical.txt file
    tropical.clear();
    tropical.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        for(int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++)
        {
            if(names[i].stormCat == 0)
            {
                for(int j = 0;j<count;j++){
                    if(names[i].ID != name[j].ID)
                    {
                        outfile << names[i].hurricaneName << setw(15) << names[i].ID << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


}
```

and it is causing me a lot of headaches.

This is supposed to print out

EXCEPTION REPORT 2

The Following Tropical Storms were not listed in the Tropical Storm data list.

Name     ID

Carla    194

Kathleen 173

but instead, I am getting more than I thought I would:

```
EXCEPTION REPORT 2

            The Following Tropical Storms were not listed in the Tropical Storm data list.

NAME                  ID


Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Carla                 194
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
Kathleen              173
```

Can someone let me know where I have my logical error? I know it is one because I am getting more than I asked for or want. Its suppose to check to see if `names[i].ID` is in the same file as `name[j].ID` and if `names[i].ID == 0`. If those conditions are true then the program should print it on the output file.

Comment: `int count = /*..*/;Tropicals name[count]` is invalid C++, it uses VLA extension. use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You do not rrad from `tropical`, that seems a bit suspicious. Also I would think your code want to check if one of your hurricane matches any of your tropical storms and not print it out everytime it doesn't match one. So, you probably want to write an or in the inner loop and then output a name if there was no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have output for each iteration of your inner loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++) {
    if(names[i].stormCat == 0) {
        for(int j = 0;j<count;j++) {
            if(names[i].ID != name[j].ID) {
                outfile << names[i].hurricaneName << setw(15) << names[i].ID << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You probably want to stop at first print:

```
for(int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++) {
    if(names[i].stormCat == 0) {
        for(int j = 0;j<count;j++) {
            if(names[i].ID != name[j].ID) {
                outfile << names[i].hurricaneName << setw(15) << names[i].ID << endl;
                break; // <<<<<<<<<< Added.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also might rewrite it with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++) {
    if (names[i].stormCat == 0) {
        if (std::find_if(names.begin(), names.end(),
                         [i](auto& name){ return names[i].ID != name.ID; }) != names.end()) {
            outfile << names[i].hurricaneName << setw(15) << names[i].ID << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42 my program worked perfectly with the `break;`